# Converting points to commas when writing data to excel using python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to implement a formula in excel file using python openpyxl. I have two sets of data: one read from excel file and one read from json. Exemplary data are as follows:

```
excel = 1.9, 1.6, 0.24
json = 2.4, 3.7, 0.58
```

I store the data in excel in two columns and try to substract one from another in a third one. I do it in a following manner:

```
ws.cell('C1').value = '=ABS(A1-B1)'
```

The formula itself works well, but the problem is that the data originally read from json file, when saved to excel have '.' instead of ',' in fractions notation. This way the result of the formula is #ARG!. When i change manually '.' to ',' the result is correct. Is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: So probably you need just to replace values after calculation. For example via `for` loop for each line.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `number_format` according to https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html :

```
ws.cell('C1').number_format = 'Comma'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses! The solution to the problem turned out to be converting string values read from json file to float in python. After that all worked well in excel.